# Type of the quotient of two integers

Tags: c++, parsing, math, logic

Consider the following:

```
int num = 5;
double total = num / 2;
```

Is it correct to say that the quotient of `num / 2` is not a `double` because you need to parse the `int` to `double`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The technical answer is that the `/` operator produces an int when given two ints.  This computation is done independent of its assignment to a `double` variable.

You actually *do* get a double value in the variable `total`, but it is 2.0, not 2.5.  The integer 2 is cast to 2.0 in the initialization.

Your options, if you want 2.5, are:

```
double total = num / 2.0;

double total = (double)num / 2;
```

In short, it is not a parsing issue, but rather one of C++ operator semantics.  Hope that made sense.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: Compared to what other languages? You get the exact same situation in other strongly-typed languages like Java and C#.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: Other languages, you mean like Python or Ruby or Java? :-P (IOW, what In silico said. :-P)

Comment: C++'s handling of the `/` operator is not too uncommon in languages that are (1) statically typed and (2) choose to overload for floating point types and integers.  Some statically typed langauges avoid overloading; Standard ML differentiates `/` for reals and `div` for ints. JavaScript doesn't even have integer division; `5/2` is just 2.5.  So many choices. :)

Comment: A third option is `double total = num * 0.5;` which I would prefer :)

Comment: I think the take-away is that if you want a double quotient, at least one operand, either the divisor or the dividend, must be cast to or expressed as a double.